# How can I prepare peeling trim for painting?

Tags: painting, paint, exterior, repainting, paint-removal

I plan to repaint the trim on our porch where some of the paint was peeling. However, in an attempt to remove that loose/peeling pieces, I'm only uncovering further layers that are peeling. How do I avoid having to sand everything to the bare wood?

[image]

Comment: For a paint job to last, you need the paint to bond with solid, not peeling, paint or wood.  Does your HOA allow you to cover/replace with plastic/metal trim?

Comment: It looks like you're being to aggressive. Usually light scraping or brushing is sufficient. Please revise to explain what you've tried in more detail, and spare us the irrelevant HOA rant and other complaining.